# Does this sentence convey my intended meaning properly? I have to write a six word story

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, comprehension

Sentence: "They acquitted guilty men for justice."

Does this sentence convey that "They acquitted guilty men **to achieve** justice," or am I not able to use the word "for" to mean "to achieve"

Comment: The word *for* has too many meanings to rely on here. How about *as justice*? Given six words only, "They" and "men" don't say much.

Comment: The phrase "for great justice" has [been pilloried](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us) for being non-idiomatic—though its non-sequitur, decontextualized, sentence-fragment use in the All Your Base exchange was the bigger issue. Context matters.

Comment: No, it doesn't really make sense.  Justice could be acquitting innocent people, or convicting guilty ones. It's hard to see how acquitting the guilty is justice.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to write this.  I suspect that you've missed the point.   The classic six-word story is  "For sale: baby clothes, never worn". The mind hears this and fills in certain details that speak of a tragic backstory.  I'm guessing you've been challenged to write something similar. If so, a simple factual statement about something that happened doesn't really work.

Comment: How does acquitting guilty men achieve justice?

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat when men are guilty of helping slaves escape to freedom. The men were guilty according to the federal law of the Fugitive Slave Act.